# How can this improper integral be solved

Tags: calculus

The fallowing improper integral looks to me divergent .But Book mentions it as convergent $$\int_2^3\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-4}\,dx,$$
Can any one set forth a hind to me ...I tried to mu test but i got no where ...

Comment: What is $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to 2^+} \int_a^3 {x^2 + 1\over x^2-4}\,dx$?

Answer (score 2):

The book is wrong.

We need to compute $$\lim_{a\to2^{+}}\int_a^3\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-4}\,dx$$

But $$\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-4}=1+\frac{5}{x^2-4}=1+\frac{5/4}{x-2}-\frac{5/4}{x+2}$$

So $$\int_a^3\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-4}\,dx=[x+5/4\ln(x-2)-5/4\ln(x+2)]_a^3$$

which is $$3-5/4\ln5-a-5/4\ln(a-2)+5/4\ln(a+2)$$

But as $a\to2^{+}$, $-5/4\ln(a-2)\to\infty$.

Comment: As i hv mentioned the question that the integral to me divergent...So there is a typo in the book...

thanks a lot sir...

Comment: @RayeesAhmad: Or you made a typo and wrote down the wrong integral, or you misread the book. There are several possibilities.